# First Order Predicate Logic with only one operator?

Tags: logic, notation, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

It's fairly well known that Propositional Logic can be expressed with only one operator -- either the [Sheffer Stroke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sheffer_stroke) (aka NAND, a dyadic operator written infix as $\vert$); or Peirce's Arrow (aka NOR, written $\downarrow$).

In First Order Predicate Logic, it's also well known that you can dispense with one of the quantifiers, using the equivalences

$$
\exists x. P(x) \equiv \lnot\forall x.\lnot P(x)
\\
\forall y. Q(y) \equiv \lnot\exists y. \lnot Q(y)
$$

I've just run across [a single-operator basis for FOL](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-combinatory/#OperNextU) due to Schönfinkel, using an operator that's a combo of Sheffer Stroke with Existential quant. It's written like a Sheffer Stroke, with the quantified variable superscripted:

$$
P(x)|^xQ(x) \equiv \lnot\exists x.(P(x) \land Q(x))
$$

It seems to be not well known(?) That Stamford Encyclopedia article calls it **nextand**, but Google doesn't bring up many refs. I'm not sure that's a happy name: my brain wants to read that as 'next-and' and indeed many of the Google hits are to temporal logic 'next-and-until'.

**Q 1.** Is **nextand** well-known in the right circles? Does it go under other aliases?

**Q 2.** Could there be other single operators as a basis for expressing FOL? I'm thinking you could base one on Peirce's Arrow; and/or you could base on universal quant:

$$
P(x)\downarrow^xQ(x) \equiv \lnot\exists x.(P(x) \lor Q(x))
\\
P(x)‽^xQ(x) \equiv \lnot\forall x.(P(x) \land Q(x))
\\
P(x)⸘^xQ(x) \equiv \lnot\forall x.(P(x) \lor Q(x))
$$

(That `‽` I've pulled out of thin air. I've used `⸘` there because mathjax in stackexchange doesn't seem to support '\textinterrodown' or '\textinterrobang' or other exotica.)

**Q 3.** Is there any reason to prefer one of the four? (I'm guessing any formula using them is going to become unreadable, so this is a purely academic exercise, right?)

The Sheffer Stroke is popular because it corresponds to a NAND gate in electronics.

Comment: Interesting! My first time hearing about "nextand". Reminds me of [Cylindric algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylindric_algebra) I guess automated theorem proving might be a potential area of application, although currently type theory seems to be dominating there.